# How to Bring Two timestamps into single row?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**strong text**

Example:

| Event | issue raised | issue closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03-08-2022 | null |
| A | null | 04-08-2022 |

Expected output :

| Event | issue raised | issue closed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 03-08-2022 | 04-08-2022 |

Comment: use to <group by> keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using aggregation with group by clause:

```
select Event, max(issue_raised) as issue_raised, max(issue_closed) as issue_closedfrom table_name
group by Event
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select Event,  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),max([issue raised]), 103) as issueraised,  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),max([issue closed]), 103) as issueclosed from Event group by Event
```

Result as

```
Event  issue raised    issueclosed 
 A      03/08/2022     04/08/2022
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do Like this :

FIRST_VALUE(issue_closed IGNORE NULLS) OVER ( PARTITION BY EVENT RANGE BETWEEN CURRENT ROW  AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) AS issues_closed_1

then table looks like

Event     issue raised          issues_closed_1

A         03-08-2022            04-08-2022

A            null               04-08-2022

Then In sub query you can filter using when condition

WHERE Event is NOT NULL

then Output will be

Event     issue raised          issues_closed_1

A         03-08-2022            04-08-2022